# Magento Rebuild Catalog product fulltext search indexing locking tables

Tags: php, magento

We have 4 stores, 
catalog products 80000+
when I do indexing of "Rebuild Catalog product full-text search index" it runs for 30 min and then breaks due to lock of tables.

the site is also very slow.

cache is enabled.

How can I do full re-index in a faster method?
Any solution/suggestion welcomed

Answer (score 0):

This process is really slow and there is a good free extension with the explanation :

http://www.dnd.fr/2012/09/magento-patch-how-to-optimize-re-index-processing-time-for-url-rewrite/

else you can have a look at this one :

https://github.com/SchumacherFM/Magento-FastIndexer